# Exporting data from Quickbooks with Ruby

Tags: ruby, quickbooks

Here's the scenario:

I will have a Quickbooks file on my local machine. I want to be able to connect to it somehow and export sales orders and purchase orders - preferably with Ruby. I've been researching this all morning and feel a bit like I'm running in circles while banging my head against the wall along the way.

Quickbooks Online looks to be suited for distributable apps, so that's obviously out the window. I've been trying the `qbwc gem` without luck so far, and even that seems like overkill.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following QBSDK docs for this use-case.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb

I'm not sure how it can be accomplished using Ruby. It is better suited for .net framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*If you're communicating with QuickBooks for Windows*, you really have two choices here -

- Use Ruby to open a COM object using the QuickBooks SDK to push data to QuickBooks directly (look up the Ruby Win32 API stuff and download the QuickBooks SDK)

OR

- Use the Ruby gem and the Web Connector to exchange data with QuickBooks (abstracted via SOAP) (this is pretty simple if you just follow the examples here: https://github.com/skryl/qbwc)

*If you're communicating with QuickBooks Online*, (which you CAN do - the QuickBooks Online API *is not limited to distributable apps*) all you have to do is send OAuth signed requests to Intuit's servers. This is likely WAY easier than communicating with QuickBooks for Windows - especially if you're already familiar with OAuth. Looks like there's some pretty easy to use Ruby gems for OAuth out there you can use: http://oauth.rubyforge.org/

If you're having *any sort of problems* you should probably post some code or error messages showing what you're running into.